# Exibição de Toast

Tags: java, android

Estou criando uma aplicativo `Android` onde tenho alguns `Switch` o qual cada um está vinculado a uma imagem. Uso uma `API` para trazê-las e faço o seu carregamento com `Image Loader`. Quando tenho um erro no carregamento das imagens uso um `Toast` para informar o usuário. O problema é que quando seleciono vários `Switch` e acontece um erro no carregamento de mais de uma imagem o `Toast` permanece na tela por muito tempo, pois ele entra mais de uma vez no `Toast`. Então queria saber como posso controlar a exibição dessa mensagem, mostrando o `Toast` uma única vez independe do número de imagens com erro no carregamento.

Exemplo do código que estou usando pra fazer o carregamento da imagem.

```
public void loading (){

final Radar finalRadar = radar;

ProductPresenter.getLastData(radar.getRadarId(), new ProductCallBack() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(final Product product) {

        final ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageLoader.loadImage(product.getUrl(), new ImageLoadingListener() {

                @Override
                public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {

                    loadImageError(finalRadar.getRadarId(), radar);

                    return;

                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {

                    addRadarOnList(product, finalRadar, loadedImage);
                    reloadSubtitle(radar);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {

                    loadImageError(finalRadar.getRadarId(),radar);

                }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onFail() {

        loadImageError(finalRadar.getRadarId(),radar);
    }

});
}



    private void loadImageError(Object componentTag, Radar radar) {

    StyleableToast.makeText(context, "Erro ao baixar imagem!", R.style.mytoast).show();

}
```

Comment: Você poderia criar um contador, acho que nesse caso funcionaria bem

Comment: @MurilloComino, eu tenho um contador nos switch, contando quantos foram selecionados, mas se eu fizer um if (contador != 1)  Toast.makeText(context, "Error ao baixar imagem!") show(); no loadImageError não vai dar no mesmo?

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução seria pegar esses `erros` e mandar para o `log`, dessa forma você saberia quais imagens deram erro. 
Creio eu que essa função `loading()` execute `n` vezes de acordo com o número de imagens que você tenha.

Edit.: como bem lembrado nos comentários, o método `loading()` executa dentro dela uma função anônima assíncrona, solicitando assim de uma verificação mais complexa.

**Exemplo de uma iteração em que ele lê as imagens**

```java
public boolean isSuccess = true;
public int size = 0;
public void executaMetodoLeitura(List<Radar> lstRadar){
  size = lstRadar.size();
  for(int i = 0; i< lstRadar.size(); i++){
    this.radar = lstRadar[i]; 
    loading(i);
  }
}
```

Com essa chamada, seria necessário criar uma função que "pega" esses valores retornados assincronamente. Ela também é responsável por verificar se o ultimo valor de chamada assíncrona foi enviado (é ela que dispara o Toast)

```java
public void consultaErro(boolean isSuccess, int index){
 if(this.isSuccess) this.isSuccess = isSucess; 

 if(index == this.size){ 
  disparaMensagem(this.isSucess);
 } 
}
```

O método de leitura ficaria dessa forma:

```java
public void loading (int index){

    final Radar finalRadar = radar;
    boolean isSuccess = true;

    ProductPresenter.getLastData(radar.getRadarId(), new ProductCallBack() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(final Product product) {

            final ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
            imageLoader.loadImage(product.getUrl(), new ImageLoadingListener() {

                @Override
                public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {

                    consultaErro(false,index);
                    Log.i("Loading Image Failed", String.format("Falha ao carregar{0}!",radar.getRadarId()));
                    return;

                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                    consultaErro(true,index);
                    addRadarOnList(product, finalRadar, loadedImage);
                    reloadSubtitle(radar);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {
                    consultaErro(false,index);
                    Log.i("Loading Image Failed", String.format("{0} : Leitura cancelada",radar.getRadarId()));
                }

                @Override
                public void onFail() {
                    consultaErro(false,index);
                    Log.i("Loading Image Failed", String.format("Ocorreu um erro ao carregar {0}",radar.getRadarId()));
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

E por fim, a função que dispara a mensagem:

```java
public void disparaMensagem(boolean isSucess){

  if(!isSuccess){
     StyleableToast.makeText(context, "Erro ao baixar imagem!", 
     R.style.mytoast).show();
  }

}
```

Existem outras maneiras de se fazer isso, as vezes seria interessante até adicionar esses dados incorretos em um array para mensagens do tipo "3 de 5 imagens não foram carregadas", mas acho que isso soluciona o seu problema.

Comment: Você está esquecendo que os métodos de *ProductCallBack* são chamados assincronamente. Quando o método *loading()* é chamado ele retorna (quase) de imediato, antes de qualquer método de *ProductCallBack* ser executado.

Comment: caramba, bem observado. O que poderia ser implementado é colocar esses retornos dentro de um método (que só é chamado depois da leitura), no caso, ele seria o que possibilitaria com que o retorno fosse o de fato constatado, isso faz sentido?

Comment: Sim, terá de ser assim.